# c# datagridview in tab control not drawing changes after first switch to tab

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabs, tabcontrol, selected

The setup:
I have a tab control and a datagridview (under the tabpageindex==2).

the datagridview is bound to a datatable.

In the tab control's tab_Selected event, if tabpageindex==2, I change some colors in some cells in the datagridview.

The problem:
The first time I select the tab with the datagridview in the application, the cells do not change color (i.e. the bound data is displayed, but my changing of colors does not work).

If I then click into another tab and back to this tab, then the colors appear.

Question:
Any idea why this is?
Should I be doing this differently, i.e. not in the tab_selected event?
(what I basically need is that certain cells have certain formats/colors depending on the data in the cells. I also e.g. call this drawing of cells function after the datagridview is sorted and there it works. just the first tab_selected event does not color...)

thanks for any help,
imran

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

After you update the cell, call `InvalidateCell()` on the `DataGridView`.

If that doesn't work, call `Invalidate()` on the `DataGridView`.

If that doesn't work, call `Invalidate()` on the `TabControl`.

Comment: Hi Gjeltema, unfortunately it did not work for me. I tried Invalidate() before and after calling my change color function in the tab_selected event => no change in behaviour.

Comment: Maybe I should not be changing the color in the tab_selected event, rather elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug with `TabControl` that **when it has more than one tab**, `cellstyles` that are created with code are only applied to the **first tab's DataGridView**, so you can move your `DataGridView` to the first tab or you can use the TabControl's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and put your styling code in this event .

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing tabs programatically while initializating styles was the solution.

```
int currentTabIndex = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
 
tabControl.SelectedTab = tab1;
dataGridView1.CustomStyleOrSomething();
tabControl.SelectedTab = tab2;
dataGridView2.CustomStyleOrSomething();
...
 
tabControl.SelectedIndex = currentTabIndex;
```

In this approach, I set the tab before applying some stuff to DataGridView that is located inside this tab. It is fast and user will not see this "change" of tabs.